# ¿Se pude usar el retorno de un procedimiento almacenado como parte de la clausula where?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedure, plsql, select

La idea es que el procedimiento almacenado me retorna un conjunto de identificadores.
Ej.
pra_id:

- 303
- 404

Actualmente es esto lo que estoy intentando hacer, y es usar el retorno de los pra_id como filtros:

```
SELECT rea.rea_id, rea.pra_id, etr.etr_id, etr.etr_codigo
    FROM tsga_registro_academico rea
   INNER JOIN tsga_estado_registro_acad etr
      ON rea.etr_id = etr.etr_id
   WHERE rea.ent_id = en_ent_id
     AND rea.pra_id = en_pra_id
     AND rea.pac_id = en_pac_id
     AND rea.coe_id = en_coe_id
     AND rea.pra_id IN
         (PKG_SGA_EQUIVAL_PROGRA_DETALLE.PRC_LIST_OBT_PRA_EQU(en_pra_id))
```

Les comparto como está declarado las entradas y salidas del procedimiento almacenado.

```
      *  %param en_pra_id     Identificador del programa acad?mico a consultar sus programas academicos equivalentes
  *  %param sq_resultados cursor de referencia que almacena los resultados de la consulta
  ************************************************************************/
  PROCEDURE PRC_LIST_OBT_PRA_EQU(en_pra_id     IN NUMBER,
                                 sq_resultados OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
```

Comment: posiblemente... depende de como has definido el procedimiento. Si lo compartes en tu pregunta, podemos contestar bien la pregunta.

Comment: @sstan Hola, acabo de compartir la declaración del procedimiento almacenado para tener una mejor referencia.

Comment: Ya veo. Puede ser que mi memoria me falle, pero no es posible incluir el resultado de un procedimiento así en la consulta de la forma como deseas. Solo es posible si estás dispuesto a convertir tu procedimiento en función.

Answer (score 0):

Los procedimientos no devuelven un valor.

Las funciones sí. Y sí podes usar una función en la cláusula where aunque va a hacer más pesado el query.

Cuando se declara una función se especifica que valor devuelve (que es único), y ese valor es el que se puede usar en un query invocando a la función.

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] FUNCTION function_name
   [ (parameter [,parameter]) ]

   RETURN return_datatype    <------  Aca se declara el tipo de dato que devuelve

IS | AS

   [declaration_section]

BEGIN
   executable_section

[EXCEPTION
   exception_section]

END [function_name];
```

En algún lado del cuerpo devuelve el valor con `RETURN <valor>`.

Comment: Los procedimientos almacenados si pueden retornar un valor. Son los output que terminas usando. Ej.
    -- Invocamos el proceso de conteo de reprobaciones
    PKG_SGA_CONTROL_IMPEDIMENTO.PRC_OBT_NUMERO_REPROBACION(en_ent_id,
                                                           en_pra_id,
                                                           en_coe_id,
                                                           sn_numero);
    IF sn_numero = 2 THEN

Comment: @Pit, no es lo mismo. El procedimento tiene parametros de entra y de salida. Devolver un valor es lo que hace una función.